# Difference between [Op.And] - Sequelize.and()

Tags: sequelize.js

I need to know the difference between [Op.and] and Sequelize.and()

```
    findeAll(
    {
    ...
    having: {
    [Op.and]: ...
    }
    }) // in this case there is an error. I can't use [Op.and] if I use Sequelize.and()  there isn't error
```

Why? I don't understand the diferrence.

Answer (score 0):

The correct use of `[Op.and]` is in the `where` clause

First of all you need to pull out the property Op

```
const { Op } = require('@sequelize/core');
```

And you can use it in the FindAll method like that for example:

```
const { Op } = require('@sequelize/core');
Post.findAll({
  where: {
    [Op.and]: [
      { authorId: 12 },
      { status: 'active' }
    ]
  }
});
// SELECT * FROM post WHERE authorId = 12 AND status = 'active';
```

I'm  not aware of Sequelize.and() method but i can tell you that the right way is using the `Op method` `( AND, OR, NOT ... )` according to [Sequelize Documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html).